# List<T> parameter in API call comes with no items, but not null

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, parameter-passing

In a C# WebApi project, the API controller has a public method, accepting a parameter of List. When I define T as dynamic, or object, it works. However, when I define T as MyClass it comes with .Count == 0. I even tried using a public interface IMyClass, but has the same behaviour. We are using Swagger for the tests, not sure if this is the reason.

Controller method:

```
public async Task<int> SaveData(List<MyClass> list) { ...code here...}
```

MyClass:

```
public MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public MyClass(int id, string name, List<IOtherClass> otherList)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        OtherList = otherList;
    }

    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<IOtherClass> OtherList { get; set; }
}
```

MyOtherClass:

```
public MyOtherClass : IMyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherClass(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    List<IMyOtherClass> OtherList { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyOtherClass
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

JSON passed:

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Test name",
        "otherList": [
            {
                "id": 345,
                "name": "Another name"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Actual classes are pretty much the same, nothing complicated.
I tried using both MyClass and IMyClass as input parameters.
Also tried IEnumerable instead of List
In all cases "list" is not null, but has "list.Count == 0"
But if I use "List< dynamic > list" then "list.Count == 1", as it should be.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your json attributes have lowercase property names (e.g. `otherList`) whilst your class has title case property names (e.g. `OtherList`).

Comment: For the `List<IOtherClass>` property, the framework has no idea how to instantiate an instance of `IOtherClass` since it is an interface. Use a concrete type here.

Comment: I have another method in the API, where it returns MyClass list, and this is what it returns. I am copying the same JSON to use as a post.

Comment: I'd bet on your class having no public parameterless constructor, if you're deserializing from json, you need either a parameterless constructor, or to "tag" one of your constructor with an attribute `[JsonConstructor]` for newtonsoft and/or System.Text.Json

Comment: Apart from the fact that you need to use a concrete class, make your properties writable, they are readonly {get;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyClass` has a couple issues, that make it unable to be deserialized :

1. No public parameterless constructor, this makes it so that the deserialization framework, cannot create an instance.

   To resolve, either create a parameterless constructor or annotate one of the constructors with `[JsonConstructor]`
2. If you went the way of creating a parameterless constructor, then the next issue become that you have only getters, so the value won't be able to be set during deserialization.
3. `OtherList` is a list of an interface type, unless the json you are deserializing includes the concrete type, (metadata $type in the json) and the deserializer is configured to take it into account, it won't know which concrete type to use for the childs.

For the case of the properties names, see @Marc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470959/2245256) or [How to enable case-insensitive property name matching (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing)

Comment: Ok, I was doing it the other way around, I had a constructor with all the parameters. Thank you.

Comment: @wizard I mean, you can absolutely do it this way, you just need to indicate which constructor should be used by the deserialization process, that and make sure the name of the parameters match the json property names (or use the JsonProeprty attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contain lowercase names, however you classes have PascalCase property names.

You can try and change your JSON to have PascalCase names, or you can add the JsonProperty attribute to your MyClass properties to specify the binding, here's the Name property as an example:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```